# Ajax is not working with java servlets?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am trying to work with ajax applications with java servlets but ajax is unable to get any responses from servers,I am using it in apache tomcat, can any one tell how to use ajax with java in xampp or tomcat?

The code I am working has has `servlet.java` in `xmlhttp.open(get,servlet.java,true)`and it is not working at all, please guide me?

Servlet code:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class ValidationServlet extends HttpServlet {
/** Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
* @param request servlet request
* @param response servlet response
*/
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
boolean passed = validateDate(request.getParameter("birthDate"));
response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
String message = "You have entered an insvalid date.";

if (passed) {
message = "You have entered a valid date.";
}
out.println("<response>");
out.println("<passed>" + Boolean.toString(passed) + "</passed>");
out.println("<message>" + message + "</message>");
out.println("</response>");
out.close();
}


boolean validateDate(String date) {
boolean isValid = true;
if(date != null) {
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
try {
formatter.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
System.out.println(pe.toString());
isValid = false;
}
} else {
isValid = false;
}
return isValid;
}
}
```

This is html `Validation.html`:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" >
<html>
<head>
<title>Using Ajax for validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp;
function createXMLHttpRequest() {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
}
function validate() {
createXMLHttpRequest();
var date = document.getElementById("birthDate");
var url = "ValidationServlet?birthDate=" + escape(date.value);
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
function callback() {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
var mes =
xmlHttp.responseXML
.getElementsByTagName("message")[0].firstChild.data;
var val =
 xmlHttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("passed")[0].firstChild.data;
setMessage(mes, val);
}
}
}
function setMessage(message, isValid) {
var messageArea = document.getElementById("dateMessage");
var fontColor = "red";

if (isValid == "true") {
fontColor = "green";
}
messageArea.innerHTML = "<font color=" + fontColor + ">" å
+ message + " </font>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Ajax Validation Example</h1>
<form action="ValidationServlet" method="get">
Birth date: <input type="text" size="10" id="birthDate" 
Onchange="validate();"/></form>
<div id="dateMessage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your code. Both Javascript (AJAX call) and Java (Servlet), plus web.xml, to see, how the webapp/servlet is configured.

Answer (score 0):

In your `validate()` you have a typo:-

Change this:-

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
```

To this:-

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callback();
```

This seems like the most straight forward issue for results not showing up. There could be several other reasons possible. Please check your browser console for error messages in case this does not help.

Comment: Check your browser console for error messages and paste them in the question

Comment: What if I setcharacterencoding to utf-8

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  VM55:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined  Validation.html:51 Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined